# How to write shorter control statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

If i want to test two properties of one in javascript i have to write

```
((a test b ) && (a test c))
```

is there a way to write something like

```
(a test ( b && c))
```

for example

```
if(a === NaN || a === Infinity){…}
```

to

```
if (a === (NaN || Infinity)){…}
```

Just wondering if there were shorthands like this.

Comment: Comparing to `NaN` is useless. Even `NaN == NaN` is false, that's why there are `isNaN` and `Number.isNaN`

Comment: Yes: `if( isFinite(a))`

Comment: isFinite should be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no.

`if (a === (NaN || Infinity)){…}` would test `a === Infinity`. First it would check `(NaN || Infinity)` (evaluates to Infitity), the check.

Additionally, checking against NaN always returns false. Try it: `NaN === NaN`. Use `isNaN(a)` instead.

Comment: Yeah, with a lowercase i. That was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a shortcut:

```
if ([val1, val2, val3 /*...*/].indexOf(a) > -1){ /* ... */ }
```

or even shorter:

```
if (~[val1, val2, val3 /*...*/].indexOf(a)){ /* ... */ }
```

Note it won't work with NaN, because comparing to `NaN` is useless. Even `NaN == NaN` is false, that's why there are [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

Comment: Assuming, of course, that you're not trying to support older browsers ;)

Comment: And, further, that `NaN == NaN`, which it doesn't.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol IE8 usage is currently negligible. And `Array.prototype.indexOf` can be added easily using a [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Comment: @Oriol: I never seen this operator before '~', what is this?

Comment: @alex `~` is the [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29) operator. It can be used because `~-1` gives falsy `0`, and with other numbers it gives truly ones.

Comment: Thank you, do you know a little tip to inverse 'instanceof' result without write '=== false' or '!(... instanceof ...)' avoid double parenthesis in if statement?

Comment: @alex Try `a instanceof A<1`

Comment: I like it. Style-wise its a bit of a hack, but not bad. Thanks.